# How to spy on setState and test toHaveBeenCalled() using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Using Jest and React, How do I spy one `this.setState()` and test weather the function `hasBeenCalled()`

```
it('shall update targets when engine register has been called', () => 
{
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <LazyloadProvider>
      <p>Wow</p>
    </LazyloadProvider>
  ).instance();
  expect(wrapper.state.targets).toEqual({}); // pass
  wrapper.engine.register(FIXTURE.REACT_REF); // pass
  expect(wrapper.state.targets).not.toEqual({}); //pass
  expect(wrapper.setState).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fail
});
```

**Engine Getter:**

```
  get engine() {
    return {
      state: this.state,
      register: target => {
        this.setState(LazyloadUtils.registerOneTarget(target));
      },
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to check for the key in state object that your setState method is updating

```
expect(wrapper.state('foo')).toEqual('bar')
```

IF you really want to spy on the method itself, you can mock the setState method on the component prototype. You would need to do this before creating a shallow copy of your component.

```
it('shall update targets when engine register has been called', () => 
 {
   LazyloadProvider.prototype.setState = jest.fn();
   const wrapper = shallow(
      <LazyloadProvider>
        <p>Wow</p>
      </LazyloadProvider>
    ).instance();
   expect(wrapper.setState).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }
```

Comment: Yeah this is more for brevity sake! thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to continue testing after the call to `setState`, you should spy, not mock the method

```js
it('shall update targets when engine register has been called', () => 
 {
   const setStateSpy = jest.spyOn(LazyloadProvider.prototype, 'setState');
   const wrapper = shallow(
      <LazyloadProvider>
        <p>Wow</p>
      </LazyloadProvider>
    ).instance();
   expect(setStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

   // write more tests that want the dom to update
 }
```